# Is there an easy way to encode (unicode) filename for content-disposition header in Python?

Tags: python, http-headers, content-disposition

Currently I'm converting a small project from node.js/express to python/falcon.
In node to encode a contect-disposition header I'm using this library: https://github.com/jshttp/content-disposition

```
import contentDisposition from 'content-disposition';
resp.setHeader('Content-Disposition', contentDisposition(filename));
```

Looking for a way to do this in Python.

Comment: OK, there is a library called "rfc6266" (it seems it was always on top of google search results, but due to it's name I never registered as an answer) - it should do the same, however it works only for Firefox in my tests. Not for In Chrome nor IE.

Comment: For some reason rfc6266 encodes the header as bytes, which then is stringified as `b"attachment; filename*=utf-8''..."` which is still somehow recognizable by Firefox. Converting bytes to string solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent library is called "rfc6266" (it seems it was always on top of google search results, but due to it's name I never actually looked at the page thinking it was a standard description).

```
import rfc6266
resp.set_header('Content-Disposition', rfc6266.build_header(filename).decode('iso-8859-1')) # the function returns bytes
```

Comment: "rfc6266" library seems to be abandoned (though works for me for now). Is there any other way?